# asp.net mvc validation on 2 fields - one must exist if other entered

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I have 2 text fields, text1 and text2, in my view model. I need to validate if text1 is entered then text2 must be entered and vice versa. How can this be achieved in the custom validation in the view model?

thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use implement `IValidatableObject` (from `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` namespace) for the server side validation on your View Model:

```
public class AClass : IValidatableObject 
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string SecondName { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if( (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(SecondName)) || (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(SecondName)) )
                yield return new ValidationResult("Name and Second Name should be either filled, or null",new[] {"Name","SecondName"});
        }
    }
```

Now it make sure if both Name and SecondName are set, or null, then model is valid, otherwise, it's not.

Comment: FYI, I recommend not returning the fields in the validation result when using a validation summary. If you return both the fields in the validation result, the validation summary will contain two messages instead of the expected single message.

Comment: Can you include some code for how this would be used to annotate class properties too please?

Answer (score 1):

Look at mvc foolproof validation it does conditional validation. Find it on nuget or http://foolproof.codeplex.com

Edit
The above is really old

I'd recommend MVC Fluent Validation for anything modern https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html

Comment: This is now very old and I wouldn/t recommend

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery, something like this:

```
$("input[x2]").hide();
    $("input[x1]").keypress(function() {
          var textValue = ("input[x1]").val();
         if(textValue) 
                      $("input[x2]").show();
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to use a data annotation validator and validation attributes on your model, you should take a look at this:
" [attribute dependent on another field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713281/attribute-dependent-on-another-field/5079585#5079585)"