# How can I compare two dates in razor mvc?

Tags: c#, razor

Given the following codes:

My razor code is this one:

```
<body>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
     <tr>
        <td>Date: </td>
        <td>
            <div class="form-group input-group-sm">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartDate)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartDate, new { @class = "form-control datepicker", placeholder = "Enter Drop-off date here..." })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDate)
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>end date: </td>
        <td>
            <div class="form-group input-group-sm">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EndDate)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EndDate, new { @class = "form-control datepicker", placeholder = "Enter Drop-off date here..." })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndDate)
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
 }
```

My model is this one:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [Display(Name = "From")]
    [Required]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "To")]
    [Required]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

}
```

Could you advice me a way to check if the StartDate is lower than EndDate? Thank you

Comment: please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371550/asp-net-mvc-validation-on-2-fields-one-must-exist-if-other-entered
and implement `IValidatableObject` in your model eg. ```public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if (StartDate > EndDate) yield return new ValidationResult("End date must be after start date");
        }```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this one I hope useful:

```
  @if (Model.StartDate < Model.EndDate )
  {
      //Do something
  }
```