# C# Double Range with a variable in the Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, double, range

I have two values in a `Model`, specifying the minimum and maximum balance.

I want to know if there is a way to **set the limitation within the `Model`** that enforces the values to have `MinBalance` between 0 and `MaxBalance`, and have `MaxBalance` between `MinBalance` and `Double.MaxValue`.

Currently I have:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the min value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The min value.
    /// </value>
    [Range(0.0, Double.MaxValue)]
    public decimal MinBalance { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the max value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The max value.
    /// </value>
    [Range(0.0, Double.MaxValue)]
    public decimal MaxBalance { get; set; }
```

I wanted to do something like this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the min value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The min value.
    /// </value>
    [Range(0.0, MaxBalance)]
    public decimal MinBalance { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the max value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The max value.
    /// </value>
    [Range(MinBalance, Double.MaxValue)]
    public decimal MaxBalance { get; set; }
```

Sadly, the latter gives me an error on using the variables in the Range, as it does not pick them up.

Comment: 2 Problems, the values passed to attributes need to be constants/literals they cannot be variables and also `Double.MaxValue` is greater than you can hold in a `decimal`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713281/attribute-dependent-on-another-field to create your own attribute like `DependentRange`

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom validator do to this job.