# ASP.NET MVC. How disable required validation based on a parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

I do have a entity class with some required attributes depending of a selector.

For instance: The Selector can assume "1" or "2". If selector was "1", a group of parameters shall be required. If selector is "2" another set of parameters is required.

```
class MyClass{

    public int Selector {get;set;} // 1 or 2

    public string A_required_for_1 {get;set;}
    public string B_required_for_1 {get;set;}

    public string C_required_for_2 {get;set;}
    public string D_required_for_2 {get;set;}

    public string E_Required_for_both_selectors {get;set;}

}
```

User should be able to switch between selectors during Create or Edit actions in view.

Client validation is already solved.

How can I deal with it in server validation?

Comment: it 's not "Disable Required validation attribute under certain circumstances" duplicate

Comment: Do yourself a favor and separate EDIT and CREATE functionality within your application.

Comment: @NicholasKinney I don't understood why you comment apply to the question. can you please clarify it?

Comment: If  you are strongly typing  your view with an stongly typed object then you will want to separate your objects between the EDIT and CREATE views. I hope this helps.

Comment: Hopefully, this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713281/attribute-dependent-on-another-field) could solve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either create your own custom validation attribute or use [MVC Foolproof Validation](https://foolproof.codeplex.com/) and then do:

```
class MyClass
{

    public int Selector {get;set;} // 1 or 2

    [RequiredIf("Selector == 1", ErrorMessage = "Your Error Message")]
    public string A_required_for_1 {get;set;}

    [RequiredIf("Selector == 1", ErrorMessage = "Your Error Message")]
    public string B_required_for_1 {get;set;}

    [RequiredIf("Selector == 2", ErrorMessage = "Your Error Message")]
    public string C_required_for_2 {get;set;}

    [RequiredIf("Selector == 2", ErrorMessage = "Your Error Message")]
    public string D_required_for_2 {get;set;}

    [Required("Your Error Message")]
    public string E_Required_for_both_selectors {get;set;}

 }
```

As mentioned by Win it does not seem to have been in active development for a while so you may want to go down the route of creating your own custom validation attribute, which does require more work but you can have a finer control over the validation itself. Choose depending on your needs.

For a custom validation attribute you could do something like this:

```
public class RequiredIfOtherProperty : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly string _otherPropertyName;
    private readonly string _compareValue;

    public RequiredIfOtherProperty(string otherPropertyName, string compareValue)
    {
        _otherPropertyName = otherPropertyName;
        _compareValue = compareValue;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var otherProperty = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(_otherPropertyName);
        if (otherProperty == null)
        {
            return new ValidationResult($"Property '{_otherPropertyName}' does not exist");
        );

        var otherPropertyValue = otherProperty.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
        if (!_compareValue.Equals(otherPropertyValue))
        {
            return new ValidationResult(this.FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

It should give you a rough idea on what you can do and you can change the actual validation to however you like. You can then use it like a normal attribute e.g.

```
[RequiredIfOtherProperty("SomeProperty", "ValueToCompareWith")]
```

Comment: Nice library, but it is ***Beta*** 0.9.4517 and hasn't been updated since May 14, 2012.

Comment: What you mean by "custom validation attribute" ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe mvcfoolproof will work for this situation [https://foolproof.codeplex.com/][1]
It is also available on nuget. It adds additional validation attributes such as

```
[RequiredIf]
[RequiredIfNot]
[RequiredIfTrue]
[RequiredIfFalse]
[RequiredIfEmpty]
[RequiredIfNotEmpty]
[RequiredIfRegExMatch]
[RequiredIfNotRegExMatch]
```

It is very simple to use.

Comment: Nice library, but it is ***Beta*** 0.9.4517 and hasn't been updated since May 14, 2012.